# creating a procedure that accepts a path for JSON file

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a procedure that loads my json file into a table. How can I create the procedure in the way that it accepts the path with file name written in manually in execute?

This is my code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE main.mainRun
@json NVARCHAR(max),
@path NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
BEGIN TRY
    SELECT @json = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK @path, SINGLE_CLOB) as j;

if(ISJSON(@json)=1)
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'JSON File is valid'
        INSERT INTO main.jsontable
        SELECT GETDATE(),*
        FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.PersonDetails.Person')
        with (

            name varchar(50) '$.first_name',
            surname varchar(50) '$.last_name',
            email varchar(50) '$.email',
            age varchar(50) '$.age',
            balance varchar(50) '$.balance',
            country varchar(50) '$.country',
            registered varchar(50) '$.registered'


            )


    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'JSON File is invalid'
    END;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE();

END CATCH

END;
GO
```

For some reason it doesn't work that way, that I have written it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your `OPENROWSET` query. You need to use Dynamic Sql to pass Path as a parameter to OPENROWSET. Something like...

```
Declare  @json NVARCHAR(MAX)
        ,@path NVARCHAR(50) = 'D:\TestFile.JSON'
        ,@Sql  NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Sql = N' SELECT @json = BulkColumn
              FROM OPENROWSET (BULK ''' + @path + ''', SINGLE_CLOB) as j;'

Exec sp_executesql @Sql
                  , N'@json NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT'
                  , @json OUTPUT

-- Now use @json variable as you need to.
```

**Your Proc**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE main.mainRun
@json NVARCHAR(max),
@path NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
BEGIN TRY

    Declare @Sql  NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Sql = N'SELECT @json = BulkColumn
             FROM OPENROWSET (BULK ''' + @path + ''', SINGLE_CLOB) as j;'

Exec sp_executesql @Sql
                 , N'@json NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT'
                 , @json OUTPUT;

if(ISJSON(@json)=1)
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'JSON File is valid'
        INSERT INTO main.jsontable
        SELECT GETDATE(),*
        FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.PersonDetails.Person')
        with (

            name varchar(50) '$.first_name',
            surname varchar(50) '$.last_name',
            email varchar(50) '$.email',
            age varchar(50) '$.age',
            balance varchar(50) '$.balance',
            country varchar(50) '$.country',
            registered varchar(50) '$.registered'
            )
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'JSON File is invalid'
    END;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE();

END CATCH

END;
GO
```

Comment: thank you, but I need to make It in the way, that I can input the path in the execute function

Comment: @finsters I just showed you how you need to handle a parameter inside OPENROWSET, you could have used the code to update your proc, anyway I have added an updated version of your proc to the answer.

Comment: ok thank you, I didn't understand at first, because I'm new at this